# ajax response not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a form and lots of field, when i submit my form to database its running fine but ajax request does not send back any response.

```
function client_form_submit(){  
    $("#project_btn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                type        : "post",
                cache   :   true,
                url     : "insert_in_db/insert_project.php",
                data    : $('#project_form').serializeArray(),
                success: function(data) {                   
                $("#myNewDiv").html(data); //this gives no response             
             }
        });     
    }); 
}
```

insert_project.php file

```
include("connection.php");


    $sql = "INSERT INTO project (table field) 
    VALUES (values)";

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if($query){
    $msg = "success";
    }else{
    $msg = "Error";
    }

echo $msg;
```

and i am trying to show above msg into my

```
<div id="myNewDiv"></div>
```

but it showing nothing

Comment: Check out if there are errors on the page and check if there is a response with firbug (for FF) or chrome developer tools

Comment: Try console.log(data); or alert(data); first... did you try it..?

Comment: try removing the `click` function from the `client_form_submit` function

Comment: BTW Why do you have a click event in you submit function?

Comment: first check whether your request going to that particular page by die('test'); or something like this in the starting of the page. if its comes there there should be problem in the php script. And while your using client event with in theclient_form_submit function.?

Comment: Use the error handler of $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

meant to post my comment as an answer, try removing the `click` function from the `client_form_submit` function:

```
 $("#project_btn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type        : "post",
            cache   :   true,
            url     : "insert_in_db/insert_project.php",
            data    : $('#project_form').serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {                   
            $("#myNewDiv").html(data); //this gives no response             
         }
    });     
});
```

Also, can you give any errors that firebug returns and check the parameters being posted and the xhr response aswell?

Comment: martincarlin87 -- i did it what you said but not help me.

Comment: have you tried turning on error reporting to see if anything is flagged by that? I haven't used `serializeArray` before, I usually use `serialize` but I assume they do the same thing. Have you also tried visiting `insert_project.php` directly in the browser to see if you see a message displayed?

Comment: martincarlin87
if i try to give direct url of insert_project.php in form action then it will give me a proper msg, but if i make this through ajax it shows nothing.
now i am trying to make it all again, deleted all files.
Thanks to all for response me....!

Comment: no problem. What I meant was actually navigating to that page in the browser, not to make it the action of your form. I think it should work but there must be something silly somewhere causing it to break.

Comment: yes you are right, there must a be some silly mistake, after all i am a novice in this field, thnx for your support...:)

Answer (score 0):

make a alert in response like that

```
success: function(data) { 
   alert(data);      
   $("#myNewDiv").html(data); //this gives no response             
  }
```

and tell me what you get.

if you are using mozilla then install firebug and go to its net tab and after that execute your submit button and see what response you have got.

Comment: alert(data); 
does not give any response.
i tried before submit the question

Comment: can you post insert_project.php here so that i can see what is the exact problem.

Comment: To get a response you need to echo the response. have you do that.